# The output of "nm" includes some symbol start with "." on AIX, what is it?

Tags: aix, nm

I'm looking at the output of "nm -t x jep.so" in AIX.
Found some symbols start with dot(".") like following:
.PyArg_ParseTuple    T  0x00079880
What does this mean?

Thanks!

Comment: One of them is the actual code, the other is the _function descriptor._ Details here: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0011

Comment: Thank you, @LorinczyZsigmond